# Make outlook 2003 macro work when word is the editor?

Tags: vba, ms-word, outlook

What I have, is a similar piece of code & i made it work with the outlook editor (hard enough) and I am trying to get it to now work with Word acting as the outlook editor. (Users are used to word mail) I tried: To move the code directly into word under this document and it did nothing. To follow code i saw on: creating an objword objdoc and then pairing it with the outlook class type of deal, with no luck.  Here is a sample of code:

```
Sub SetCategory()
Dim olMessage As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMessage = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
If olMessage.SenderName = donations Then
olMessage.Categories = "donations"
ElseIf olMessage.SenderName = "Donations" Then
olMessage.Categories = "donations"
End If
With olMessage
    .Send
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I found that in word i should have created it under the normal module so that it can be applied to any word document. But i still am stumped as to make the code work in a way that is compatible with word. Please help!!!!1

Comment: Please revise your question to include a clear and concise problem statement. Does this code error? If so, at what line and what is the error message?  Also, what is the desired result? What are you trying to accomplish? You've basically just given a snippet of code and says "This doesn't work".  But how can anyone help you if you don't describe what you need, or what the specific failure is?

Comment: The above snippet is working code, provided as an example. I thought it necs

Comment: The above snippet is working code for an outlook macro called set category, The purpose of it is to set a new messages category to donations, when a user is emailing on behalf of another mapi account named donations. The macro is followed up with a filter which places sent items -with the category of 'donations' into the mapi sent folder. This entire process works in my test environment until I change the email editor to word, a setting which mimics my user's, at which point macros are greyed out (in a new message where i want to make a button

Comment: Reason being, that i created the existing macro in outlook and it needs to be created in Word. Then i can create a button on new compositions and attach the macro. If i take the code and copy it directly into a word module, it cancels out at Outlook.MailItem saying unknown definition. I have seen people who have taken outlook macro code and made it work with word and I cant seem to make it work. How do I go about this?

Comment: What part of "revise the original question" was unclear?

Comment: Comments dont help much when you could put them in the questin; some just read the question and dont look at comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using "word mail" you are not using Outlook. This describes how to invoke Outlook from Word. Once Outlook is open you can use Outlook VBA.

http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/senddocasmail.htm

Untested, and you will have to remove the parts you do not need.

```
Sub SendDocAsMail()

Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem

On Error Resume Next

'Start Outlook if it isn't running
Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

On Error GoTo 0 ' <=== Important to see errors now if there are any

'Create a new message
Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


' --------------------------
'Set oItem = oOutlookApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
If oItem.SenderName = donations Then
oItem.Categories = "donations"
ElseIf oItem.SenderName = "Donations" Then
oItem.Categories = "donations"
End If
' --------------------------



'Allow the user to write a short intro and put it at the top of the body
Dim msgIntro As String
msgIntro = InputBox("Write a short intro to put above your default " & _
            "signature and current document." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Press Cancel to create the mail without intro and " & _
            "signature.", "Intro")

'Copy the open document
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy
Selection.End = True

'Set the WordEditor
Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim wdEditor As Word.Document
Set objInsp = oItem.GetInspector
Set wdEditor = objInsp.WordEditor

'Write the intro if specified
Dim i As Integer
If msgIntro = IsNothing Then
    i = 1
    'Comment the next line to leave your default signature below the document
    wdEditor.Content.Delete
Else
    'Write the intro above the signature
    wdEditor.Characters(1).InsertBefore (msgIntro)
    i = wdEditor.Characters.Count
    wdEditor.Characters(i).InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard
    wdEditor.Characters(i + 1).InsertParagraph
    i = i + 2
End If

'Place the current document under the intro and signature
wdEditor.Characters(i).PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

'Display the message
oItem.Display

'Clean up
Set oItem = Nothing
Set oOutlookApp = Nothing
Set objInsp = Nothing
Set wdEditor = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit: Added, based on comment. This is a step that beginners trip on.

"Since this macro also uses Outlook functionality to create the mail we must add the reference to the project. To do this choose Tools-> References… and select Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library (or 14.0 when using Outlook 2010). After this press OK."

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The "Send Word Document As" article was a big help. In fact, this was the site I visited before and could not find my way back to. Along with defining oOutlookApplication as an application the other piece was to enable the library reference within word settings. Thank you very much niton.

Comment: It Now turns out that my program, sets all emails to the category donations. This is because of the line oItem.Categories = donations that is called irregardless of the if then statement above. This almost makes no sense to me because if oItem.SenderName does not equal donations or Donations, it should skip to the end if. What am i doing incorrectly?

Comment: that was because the parentheses were removed from the first if line.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Outlook versions use Word as an email editor by default. There is no need to check out the editor type. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. You can read more about that in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) .

Also you may find the [How to automate Outlook and Word by using Visual C# .NET to create a pre-populated e-mail message that can be edited](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/819398?wa=wsignin1.0) article helpful.